# How to make link open "Maps" window when clicked

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to have a link in a web page in such a way that when the link is clicked it opens the standard "Maps" view in iPhone.

If such a thing is possible, what tag format do I need to use with the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple; you don't even need to use a specific scheme identifier. Any Google Maps URL will be opened with the Maps app automatically, as long as all the parameters are supported.

So links like these:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=cupertino
http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino
```

Would automatically be opened in Maps. To find out more about what works and what doesn't see the [Map Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html) page from the Apple URL Scheme Reference.

Comment: Thanks ... can i use the link was latitude and lontitude values?

Comment: Dude, actually read the link I provided. The answer is there.

Comment: Thanks ... apericate your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

I used this code which works passing longitude lattitude:

```
 NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@",cur_lat, cur_lon,[loc stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"current %f %f",cur_lat,cur_lon);

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```